# Brainstorm: To compute x/y in log(n) time,

Tags: algorithm

How will you compute x/y in O(log(n)) time.

n=x/y, x & y are integers

You can't use the / operator.

One implementation is to add y q times till the result is less than x i.e.

```
y * q < x
```

Comment: What is "n" - the number of bits used to represent x?

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: I assume he's talking about arbitrary precision numbers.

Comment: What about shifting `n` bits to the right as much as possible (until `2^n >= y`, and then handling the remaining division differently? (this isn't an answer, just a brainstorm/idea topic)

Comment: If using of operator / would be O(1), then it is a solution, because it is even better than O(log(N))

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: den I wudnt have asked the question

Answer (score 2):

What about 10**(log(x) - log(y))

Big O() notation only applies to how a problem scales with different number of inputs.
The question doesn't make sense unless you mean 'n' is the number of digits in x and y

Comment: dat was smart but can you give a more efficient solution